# Improve performance of neo4j query with multiple OPTIONAL MATCH

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am new to Neo4j and have a query that I want to improve. Any help or recommendations would be appreciated.

```
MATCH (s:Source),
(s)-[:SourceContext]->(c:Context),
(c)-[:ContextFunction]->(f:Function)
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)<-[*1..2]-(e:Entity)
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)<-[*1..2]-(au:Author)
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)<-[*1..2]-(p:Period)
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)<-[*1..2]-(u:Unit)
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)<-[*1..2]-(a:AttributeSet)
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)<-[*1..2]-(t:Timeseries)
WITH e,t,p,u,s,a,f,au
WHERE
(t.id in [3450] or t.id is null) AND
(e.id in [16260] or e.id is null)
AND s.id = 16
AND (a.id = 0 or a.id is NULL)
return {SourceID: s.id, EntityID: e.id, TimeSeriesID: t.id, PeriodID: p.id, UnitID: u.id, FunctionID: f.id, AttributeSetID: a.id}
```

See neo4j profile plan
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dErgQ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of traversing the whole graph, you will want to move the filtering part of the cypher queries sooner in the query.

```
MATCH (s:Source),
(s)-[:SourceContext]->(c:Context),
(c)-[:ContextFunction]->(f:Function)
WHERE s.id = 16
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)<-[*1..2]-(e:Entity)
WHERE e.id = 16260 or e.id is null
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)<-[*1..2]-(au:Author)
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)<-[*1..2]-(p:Period)
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)<-[*1..2]-(u:Unit)
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)<-[*1..2]-(a:AttributeSet)
WHERE a.id = 0 or a.id is NULL
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)<-[*1..2]-(t:Timeseries)
WHERE t.id = 3450 or t.id is null
WITH e,t,p,u,s,a,f,au
return {SourceID: s.id, EntityID: e.id, TimeSeriesID: t.id, PeriodID: p.id, UnitID: u.id, FunctionID: f.id, AttributeSetID: a.id}
```

This should greatly improve the query performance as you will be starting from only a single Source node instead of traversing all the source nodes in your graph.

It would also help if your graph model supports adding relationship types to the `OPTIONAL MATCH`es.

For example:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)<-[:HAS_AUTHOR*1..2]-(au:Author)
```

This way you avoid traversing all the relationship types in each `OPTIONAL MATCH`.
If not, there are still some improvements you could make.
You could run the

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)<-[*1..2]-(node)
```

And then filter the results based on node type:

```
CASE WHEN node:Author THEN ... ELSE ... END
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have noticed if I just move the WHERE s.id = 16 to before the OPTIONAL MATCHES in my original query. The query take much longer.

The other suggestion you made is to move the filters to just after the OPTIONAL MATCH. When trying that, I've noticed that if the OPTIONAL MATCH match a node but the property on that node is not equal to the value in the where. It still returns that row but with id as null. I want to match the id with that node if they exist but also return the value if they dont exist

Comment: Also on the [:HAS_AUTHOR*..2] it matches if the relationship is like this (c)-[:HAS_AUTHOR]-(au), but not if its like this (c)-[:HAS_AUTHOR]-(b)-[:AUTHOR2]-(au)

Comment: @Febre Why bother to do `WHERE` filtering at all for the "OPTIONAL" matches if you want to get the same results as if there was no filter? Also, `AUTHOR2` is not the same as `HAS_AUTHOR`; so this should work better: `[:HAS_AUTHOR|AUTHOR2*..2]`.

Comment: @cybersam Thanks for this `[:HAS_AUTHOR|AUTHOR2*..2]`
For the `OPTIONAL MATCH` lets assume the following scenario:
`(c1:Context)-[:ENTITY_CONTEXT]-(e1:Entity {id:1})` 
`(c2:Context)-[:ENTITY_CONTEXT]-(e2:Entity {id:2})` and
`(c3:Context) with no relationship`

If I do a `WHERE e.id = 2` after the `OPTIONAL MATCH` then I will get 3 results back c1 with e.id = null c2 with e.id =2 and c3 with e.id =null. But I am only looking for c2 and c3.

If I do the `WHERE e.id =2 or e.id is NULL` after the `WITH` then it will only return c2 and c3 as expected, because c1 will have e.id =1